# Play 2 different sounds through 2 different sinks/audio outputs on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

I have 2 audio sinks on my raspberry pi (running Ubuntu 20.10). One is my monitor with build in speakers (hdmi) and a headphone jack. I have 2 applications running (Firefox and Rhythmbox) and I want the audio coming from Firefox to go through sink x and the audio from Rhythmbox to go through sink y

This answer here says: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484010/setting-pulseaudio-playback-device-before-playback

`By default, PulseAudio will attempt to remember where each application's output was directed  the last time it was used, and keep using that output device for it until told otherwise. If there is no record of previous use, the fallback device is used.`

But is this even correct? By default they both go through 1 sink. In PulseAudio I have a dropdown to select to which audio-output each source (FF or RB) goes. When I change this manually this works fine. But every time I reboot I have to manually change that the audio coming from FF has to go through another sink and, as said, by default they both go through 1 sink. The answer states that PulseAudio remembers where each applciation's output was redirected to and yet this gets reset or something....

How can I make this change permanent? Or is there a script that I can use that sets the correct application to the correct sink at startup or something?

I basically want something like this: [Assign programs permanently to different sound-outputs in Pulseaudio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24340/assign-programs-permanently-to-different-sound-outputs-in-pulseaudio)

With the problem being that the accepted answer basically boils down to "wait until the problem fixes itself"....